# Cross-database & multiple data connections

Tags: mysql

How bad is it to have 4-5 connections on a single page?  Is it like, horribly bad?

I mean to different databases.  I have the following databases....

core
account
ads
starcraft
diablo
forums
development

It's common for a few to be loaded each time a page is loaded.  I do utilize a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) cache.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit?  4 or 5 connections to different databases, or 4 or 5 connections to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

Well its not going scale if your site grows..

You have wait-io on not 1 call but 5.. im guessing that this will eventually slow down..
(what happens when 1 call fails?? you have 5 x the risk here too )

Once it does get slow.. You will try to cache more ( but the real problem is the way you structured your data )

To be honest, I would consider going over it again now, and getting it right before you find yourself a user base / community

Hope this helps.. :D

Comment: Dang... so it's better to have 200 tables in a single database?

Comment: Just 200?  Ah, so quite a small database then :)  Nearly 600 in the one I'm working on.